# Pass an OBJECT PARAMETER by reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, parameters, pass-by-reference

I have a question that sounds a lot like a dumb question, so please read thoroughly. I have a section of code that creates a label. That label needs to be updated frequently to match the changing value of one of my objects' parameters. I've built a constructor function(I think?) to build this label, and I want the label to know where the information is that is needs to update itself with.

That information is an object parameter. I need to do this for many different parameters of the same object. Is there a way to pass the reference of this parameter so that the label can access when it needs to update itself?

```
b.name="foo";
b.other="bar";
b.anotherThing="foobar";

function initiateDisplayDiv(b, value, classString){

        var div=document.createElement("div");
        div.id=b.name+classString+"Display";
        div.className=classString;
        self.bCtnr.appendChild(div);
        div.innerHTML=value;
        div.dispObject=value;

        return div;
    }
```

Where `value` is actually a parameter of b, but I need to do this for `other` and `anotherThing` (and like 200 more times for a, c, d... with like 30 more parameters each)

Any recommendations? Did I miss something obvious? Should I just write it out for all 30 or so parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your problem but what about making a function that gets the parameter you need ?

Something like :

```
function getParameter(obj, param) {
    return obj[param]; 
}
```

Then you can do (instead of *value*):

```
getParameter(b, "name");
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I did not know you could access object properties that way. I hope that someone else like me finds this answer one day